# How to insert IMCE button into WYSIWYG toolbar in custom module with jquery?

Tags: jquery, ckeditor, toolbar

I created a module and i want to insert imce button in toolbar of editor.
I have code:

```
CKEDITOR.replace(id,{
                    height:"200",
                    width: "800",
                    resize_enabled : 'false',
                    resize_maxHeight : '200',
                    resize_maxWidth : '800',
                    toolbar : 
                    [
                        { name: 'basicstyles', items : [ 'Bold','Italic','Underline','-','RemoveFormat' ] },
                        { name: 'paragraph', items : [ 'NumberedList','BulletedList'] },
                        { name: 'links', items : [ 'Link','Unlink', 'Image', 'Table'] },
                        { name: 'regularstyles', items : [ 'Superscript' , 'Subscript' ]} ,
                        { name: 'SpecialChar', items: ['SpecialChar'] },
                        { name: 'clipboard', items : [ 'Cut','Copy','Paste','PasteText','PasteFromWord', 'Find' , 'Replace' , 'Undo' , 'Redo' ] },
                        { name: 'tools', items : [ 'Source' ] },
                        { name: 'tools', items : [ 'Maximize' ] },
                    ],
                });
```

I tried insert code:

```
{ name: 'links', items : [ 'Link','Unlink', 'IMCE', 'Table'] },
```

but it was not run. 
Please help me.